# Unwanted space in a PDF generated with TCPDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

We use TCPDF to generate PDFs. In one special case I got a strange behaviour, it looks like TCPDF puts a space inbetween two characters.

I use the cid0cs as font, the strange behaviour appears if I place "µg" in the PDF, it looks like "µ g" (with some space inbetween) now.

I edited the cid0cs.php on index 181 (like here: http://bytethinker.com/blog/correct-display-of-imported-fonts-in-tcpdf) with no success.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the character µ or g? If you select the letters you can see which letter the extra space belongs to. So... for a small "g" (the first letter after which is the space, you must edit the entry "130=>???" of the $cw array.

```
$cw=array(0=>0,1=>750,2=>750,3=>750,4=>750
```

Make it half the value. If its 750, make it 400 and try. Or even better: search for a letter that could be the same with as your "g" (an "a" for example).

Cheers,

Guido
(customer service is when you look at all the links that lead to your website :)